# Why the scale factor of the product of two gaussian functions is the convolution of the same gaussian functions?

Tags: convolution, products, gaussian

The product of two Gaussian functions

$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_{f}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2 \sigma_{f}^{2}} \right) \quad \text { and } \quad g(x-y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_{g}} \exp\left(-\frac{\left(x-y\right)^{2}}{2 \sigma_{g}^{2}}\right)
$$

is another Gaussian function with standard deviation and mean

$$
\sigma_{f g}=\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{f}^{2} \cdot \sigma_{g}^{2}}{\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}}} \qquad\qquad \mu_{f g}=\frac{y\cdot\sigma_{f}^{2}}{\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}}
$$

rescaled by

$$
S(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\left(\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}\right)}} \exp \left[-\frac{y^{2}}{2\left(\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}\right)}\right]
$$

Thus, the product is

$$
f(x) \cdot g(x-y)=\frac{S(y)}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma_{f g}} \exp \left[-\frac{\left(x-\mu_{f g}\right)^{2}}{2 \sigma_{f g}^{2}}\right]
$$
Namely, a rescaled Gaussian function. The scaling factor is equivalent to
$$
S(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \cdot g(x-y) dx = [f * g](y)
$$

In other words, the scaling factor of the product of two Gaussian functions is exactly the result of the convolution of the two Gaussians. It doesn't seem to be a coincidence.
Is there any deep reason why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? The product of two normalized Gaussians is not normalized, while convolving two normalized functions is also normalized.

Comment: @user619894 I never said that the product of two Gaussians is normalized. On the contrary, the resulting Gaussian is multiplied by the scaling factor. Anyway, I am not interested in normalization factors, I am more interested in the "shape" of the scaling factor, which happens to be exactly the convolution of the two Gaussians.

Answer (score 0):

The [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_convolutions_of_probability_distributions#Continuous_distributions) of the two Gaussians is
$$\tag{1}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\left(\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}\right)}} \exp \left[-\frac{\left(\color{red}{x\,-\,}\mu_{f}-\mu_{g}\right)^{2}}{2\left(\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}\right)}\right].
$$
You are saying that this convolution is equal to the product of the two PDFs
when we set $\mu_f=\mu_g=0\,.$
Let's check
\begin{align}
f(x)g(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\left(\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}\right)}}  \exp \left[-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_f^2}-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_g^2} \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\left(\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}\right)}}  \exp \left[-\frac{\sigma_g^2x^2+\sigma_f^2x^2}{2\,\sigma_f^2\,\sigma_g^2}\right]\\
&=
\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi\left(\sigma_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{g}^{2}\right)}}}_{\text{ very good }}  \exp \underbrace{\left[-\frac{(\sigma_g^2+\sigma_f^2)\,x^2}{2\,\sigma_f^2\,\sigma_g^2}\right]}_{(???)}\,.\tag{2}
\end{align}
To me this looks different from the convolution (1) even when we assume $\mu_f=\mu_g=0\,.$

Without further background I don't think that the product is very interesting. What is more interesting are

- the product $f(x)\,g(\color{red}{y})$ which is -as we know- the PDF of the joint distribution of two independent Gaussians;
- the integral $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\exp(-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2t})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\exp(-\frac{(z-y)^2}{2s})\,dz=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(t+s)}\exp(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2(t+s)})$ which shows that the Brownian heat kernels are a ***convolution semigroup***.

Comment: Dear Kurt, thank you for your reply. However, I explicitly stated that $S(x)$ is the convolution of the two original Gaussian *centered in the origin*, so $\mu_f = \mu_g = 0$ in the calculus of the convolution I show. As I said, it doesn't feel like this result is a coincidence. The reason why I think so is that for a calculation I performed with some precise physical meaning, I was expecting to get the convolution of two Gaussians. Instead I get the scaling factor. However, it happens to be exactly the convolution I was expecting. It feels like there is some hidden math behind.

Comment: I see. Checking this I don't see that $S(x)$ equals the convolution. See edit.

Comment: Dear Kurt, thanks again for your time. Unfortunately, I might not have explained myself properly. I am not claiming that the product and the convolution of two Gaussians are the same. I am saying that the scaling factor of the product is the convolution. I am not asking for a check, this is very easy to confirm. I am asking if that's a coincidence or if some non-trivial math is happening under the carpet. See edit in my question.

Comment: @DrManhattan . OK . The only thing I can think of is that the Gaussian density is a very symmetrical function . If there is any non trivial math behind your formulas could be found out by looking at other densities . In other words : what properties single out the normal density from general densities ? Perhaps you found a new one. I don't know.